# Spring REST API deployed on Heroku is timing out when trying to create a new user. However the user is created? but I get 503 instead of 201 status

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, heroku, axios

So I have an application with an open controller for creating a new user, when I test this on postman and on my local machine it works, however when I try it on my deployed app it does not. Heroku is saying that I have a timeout issue.

Also the post is actually working because when I check if the user is posting with the get request I get the newly created user, it appears like the issue is somewhere between creating the user and trying to get the 201 created status sent back. Any help would be greatly apprecaiated! Below are the open controller and the registration js for quick reference. However I cant fit everything on here so this is the repo if you need to see other files: https://github.com/robertmasters/pokehuddleSpringApp/tree/main/pokehuddlebackend

this is the open controller

```
@RestController
public class OpenController {

    @Autowired
    UserServices userServices;

    @Autowired
    RoleServices roleServices;

    //http:/localhost:2019/createnewuser
    //body -> username, password, email

    @PostMapping(value = "/createnewuser", consumes = {"application/json"}, produces = {"application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> addSelf(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @RequestBody UserMinimum newminuser)  throws Exception {
        //create new user
        User newuser = new User();
        //set up needed data
        newuser.setUsername(newminuser.getUsername());
        newuser.setPassword(newminuser.getPassword());
        newuser.setEmail(newminuser.getEmail());
        //set up roles that is needed
        Set<UserRoles> newRoles = new HashSet<>();
        newRoles.add(new UserRoles(newuser, roleServices.findByName("USER")));

        //save it
        newuser = userServices.save(newuser);

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        //http://localhost:2019/users/user/id
        URI newUserURI = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(httpServletRequest.getServerName() + ":" + httpServletRequest.getLocalPort() + "/users/user/{userid}")
                        .buildAndExpand(newuser.getUserid()).toUri();
        responseHeaders.setLocation((newUserURI));


        //make it so that user can register and receive access token after registering
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        //creating the url to call
        String requestURI = "http://" + httpServletRequest.getServerName() + ":" + httpServletRequest.getLocalPort() + "/login";

        //sending application json
        List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        //headers and body that goes with request
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
        //authorization part of header
        headers.setBasicAuth(System.getenv("OAUTHCLIENTID"), System.getenv("OAUTHCLIENTSECRET"));

        //include username and password
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("grant_type", "password");
        map.add("scope", "read write trust");
        map.add("username", newminuser.getUsername());
        map.add("password", newminuser.getPassword());

        //all headers go into a single request
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        //plain string in json format that has access token
        String theToken = restTemplate.postForObject(requestURI, request, String.class);

        //return access token in body as well as body and status of created
        return new ResponseEntity<>(theToken,
                responseHeaders,
                HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

here is the registration file

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm, useWatch } from "react-hook-form"
import axios from "axios";
import { axiosWithAuth } from "../../utils/axiosWithAuth";
const client = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID
const secret = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
function Register() {
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false)
 const [loginError, setLoginError ] = useState()
 const { register, watch, formState: {errors}, handleSubmit } = useForm({mode: "onBlur"})
 const navigate = useNavigate()

 function goToLogin (data) {
  const body = JSON.stringify(
    {
      "username": data.username,
      "password": data.password,
      "email": data.email,
      "articles": [],
      "roles": [
     {
      "role": {
       "roleid": 2,
       "name": "user"
      }
     }
    ]}
  )
  console.log("body: ", body)
  setIsLoading(true)
  axios
  .post(
    "https://masters-pokehuddlerest.herokuapp.com/createnewuser",
    body,
    // {timeout: 40000}, tried this but didnt work?
  {
    headers: {
     Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${client}:${secret}`).toString("base64")}`,
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }})
  .then((res) => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    console.log("response: ", res)
    navigate("/")
  })
  .catch((err)=> {
    setIsLoading(false)
    setLoginError("Registration Error please try again")
    console.log(err)
  })
 }
 const password = watch("password")

 return (
  <div className = "main-container">
    <div>Registration not fully set up,<Link className = "link" to ="/">click here </Link>to go back to login</div>

   <div className = "middle-section">
    <div className = "ashPikaimg-container">
        <img className ="ashpikaimg" src = {require("../../images/ashpika.png").default} alt = "Ash and Pikachu landing page" />
    </div>

    <div className= "login-section">
     <div className = "description login-flex-item">
      <div className = "registration-prompt">
       <div className ="reg-desc">Welcome to PokeHuddle!</div>
      </div>                
     </div>

     <div className = "selection login-flex-item">
      Already a member? &nbsp;
      <Link to ="/" className = "select-logreg">Login</Link>
     </div>

     <form className = "login-flex-item" onSubmit = {handleSubmit(goToLogin)}>
     {
      loginError ? <span role = "alert" className="error-message">{loginError}</span> : null
     }
     <input className = "form-item"
      type = "text"
      name = "username"
      placeholder = "Username"
      data-testid="username-input"
      {...register("username", { required: "Username is required" })}
     />
      {errors.username && (
       <p 
       role = "alert" className="error-message">{errors.username.message}</p>
      )}

     <input className = "form-item"
      type = "email"
      name = "email"
      placeholder = "Email"
      data-testid="email-input"
      {...register("email", {
       required: "Email is required" ,
       pattern : {
        value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
        message: "invalid email address"
       }
      })}
     />
    {errors.email && (
     <p 
     role = "alert" className="error-message">{errors.email.message}</p>
    )}

     <input className = "form-item"
      type="password"
      name="password"
      placeholder = "Password"
      data-testid="password-input"
      {...register("password", { required: "Password is required" })}
     />
     {errors.password && (
        <p 
        role = "alert" className="error-message">{errors.password.message}</p>
     )}
     <input className = "form-item relative"
      type="password"
      name="confirm-password"
      placeholder = "Confirm Password"
      data-testid="confirm-password-input"
      {...register("confirmPassword", {required: "Please confirm password", validate: (value) => value === password || "Passwords do not match"  })}
     />
     {errors.confirmPassword && (
      <p 
      role = "alert" className="error-message">{errors.confirmPassword.message}</p>
     )}
     { isLoading ? <span>Loading...</span> : 
     <button className = "form-item btn">Register</button> }
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 );
};

export default Register;
```

and this is the heroku logs that give me the timeout error

```
2022-03-10T18:26:22.851591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/createnewuser" host=masters-pokehuddlerest.herokuapp.com request_id=ecd8ef78-e4d2-4d77-bef9-6b2b51849af8 fwd="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=220 protocol=https
2022-03-10T18:26:52.891397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/createnewuser" host=masters-pokehuddlerest.herokuapp.com request_id=1342fed3-2d97-4792-8614-1394a723fb89 fwd="xxxxxxxxxx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383651+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-03-10 18:28:31.383 ERROR 4 --- [io-29682-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://masters-pokehuddlerest.herokuapp.com:29682/login": Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)] with root cause
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383664+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383665+00:00 app[web.1]: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383665+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383666+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383666+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383666+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383667+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383667+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383668+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383668+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383669+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383669+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383669+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383669+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383670+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383670+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383670+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383670+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383671+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383672+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383672+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383673+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:739) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383673+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383673+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:418) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383673+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.pokehuddle.pokehuddlebackend.controllers.OpenController.addSelf(OpenController.java:87) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383674+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383674+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383674+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383674+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383675+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383675+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383676+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383680+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383681+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383681+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383681+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383682+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383682+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383682+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383682+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383682+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383683+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383683+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383683+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383683+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383683+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383683+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383683+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383684+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383684+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383684+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383684+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383684+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383684+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383685+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383685+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383685+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383685+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383688+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383688+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383689+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383689+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383689+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383689+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383690+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383690+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383690+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383691+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383691+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383691+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383691+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383692+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383692+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383692+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383692+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383693+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383693+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383693+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383693+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383693+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383693+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383694+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383694+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383701+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383701+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383702+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383702+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383702+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383702+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383703+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383703+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.pokehuddle.pokehuddlebackend.config.SimpleCorsFilter.doFilter(SimpleCorsFilter.java:58) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383703+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383703+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383704+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383704+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383704+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383704+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383705+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383705+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383705+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383705+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383705+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383705+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383705+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383706+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383706+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383706+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383706+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383706+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383706+00:00 app[web.1]:    atjava.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
2022-03-10T18:28:31.383706+00:00 app[web.1]:
```